# Necessary nodes in Web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

What are the necessary nodes in my `Web.config` file? I'm using `VS 2012` though my project is `ASP.NET MVC 3` type.

I'm not using `Entity Framework`. And I'm using forms authentication mode with one admin user.

Should I keep these nodes then:

- `configSections` as well as its content (`<section name="entityFramework" ...`);
- `profile`, `membership`, `roleManager` as well as their content;
- `entityFramework`. Obviously I don't need it;
- `connectionStrings` contains `DefaultConnection` definition on which `sessionState`→`providers`→`DefaultSessionProvider` depends.

Need your guidance a little. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using EF, then you don't need either the entityFramework section or its respective node under configSections. If there are no other special configSections, you can remove that whole node altogether.

You do not need profile, membership, or roleManager unless you are using them in conjunction with your 1 admin login account.

If you are not using any databases, you can delete the connectionStrings as well. sessionState does not really use the DefaultConnection when you run it InProc. I don't know why they put that attribute on the sessionState node.

Comment: So should I leave `DefaultSessionProvider`?

Comment: If you are not using session anywhere in your application, I think you may be able to delete the whole `system.web/sessionState` section.